# How can I display a list in reverse with 3 colon-separators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice, reverse

how can get the 3rd line to do the same as the second line?

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(list[::-1])
print(list[-1:0:-1])
```

this is the result i got:

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Comment: With `s[-1:-len(s)-1:-1]`

Answer (score 3):

You should omit 0 here:

```
print(list[-1:0:-1])
```

and write it as

```
print(list[-1::-1])
```

or place `None`:

```
print(list[-1:None:-1])
```

The reason is: when you omit the *stop* value (or substitute `None`) in a "3 colon-seperators", [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) will happen:

> If *i* or *j* are omitted or `None`, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of *k*).

where `j` here corresponds to the stop value (and `i` is the start i.e. `[i:j:k]`)

Answer (score 2):

Use `None`:

```
>>> list[-1:None:-1]
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

or

```
>>> list[None:None:-1]
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

You could use `-len(list)-1`, but `None` is simpler and doesn't require any computation.

BTW `list` is a bad variable name since it shadows the builtin [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Answer (score 1):

You can use following ways of list slicing to achieve required result.

```py
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

#Use Blank:
print(list[::-1])
print(list[-1::-1])
#output
#[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

#Use None:
print(list[:None:-1])
print(list[None:None:-1])
#output
#[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

#Use Boolean:
print(list[-True::-True])
#output
#[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

#Use Boolean:
print(list[~False::-1])
#output
#[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]


#Use of Length function:
print(list[:-(len(list)+1):-1])
#output
#[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```